# Sorting a list based on status using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

would anyone help me solving this query.,,

I have a List which needs to sorted based on the status column.
sample list.

```
IList<Letters> lstLetterSummary = new List<Letters>();
```

Letters datacontract

```
public class ERDRMessageSummary
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string LetterId{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
    public string MessageType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 4)]
    public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 5)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 7)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 8)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

     }
```

the list contains a member called  status as you can see in the contract, value can be:
1.Registered.
2.Waiting to sent.
3.Sent.
4.Rejected.

the list needs to sort based on the status value and should be in the below order.
1.Rejected.
2.waiting to sent.
3.sent.
4.registered.

am using c# and linq for this..

any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad29ab8b-85d6-4745-89ac-b2016de5c126/custom-linq-sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define a method that translates your status string into a numeric value corresponding to the desired order:

```
int GetStatusOrder(string status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case "Rejected"        : return 1;
        case "Waiting to sent" : return 2;
        case "Sent"            : return 3;
        case "Registered"      : return 4;
        default                : return 5;
    }
}
```

Then, you could use the LINQ `OrderBy` operator and call this method:

```
var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(l => GetStatusOrder(l.Status)).ToList();
```

This is just a quick-and-dirty solution for when you can't alter your class. If possible, you should convert the type of your `Status` field from string to an enumeration type.

Comment: I thought of this solution first in my mind but after reading the meike's answer, looks like using a `Dictionary` is faster and shorter (although the difference in this case (only 4 entries) is very very small).

Comment: @KingKing A `Switch` is implemented as a hash based lookup structure, just like a `Dictionary`, so the performance should be comparable between them.

Comment: @Servy do you mean the `compiler` will convert the `switch` to the same thing that `Dictionary` does?

Comment: @KingKing Yes, or at least comparable code, even if it doesn't use the `Dictionary` type, per say.

Comment: @Servy thank you, nice to know about that. However, it's still a little lengthier.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
string[] statuses = { "Rejected", "Waiting", "To send", "Sent", "Registered" }; 
Dictionary<string, int> OrderingDictionary =
  statuses
  .Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
  .ToDictionary(z => z.x, z => z.i);

List<string> orderedData =
  lstLetterSummary
  .OrderBy(s => OrderingDictionary[s])
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this? It is so simple :)

```
string[] statuses = { "Rejected", "Waiting to send", "Sent", "Registered" };
lstLetterSummary.Sort((x, y) =>
{
     return Array.IndexOf(statuses, x.Status).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(statuses, y.Status));
});
```

Comment: @Anirudh Lazy ppl like me find how to solve problems easily :)

Comment: Concise but very inefficient. You're looking up the index of the status along the array for each sort comparison operation.

Comment: @Douglas Agree with you, but for just 4 element it won't be much loss in performance is what I think. Doing so will give micro optimizations only. If more elements included I'll go with `Dictionary` idea of meilke

Comment: Sriram: You're right in that respect. You could make the code conciser by using LINQ: `lst = lst.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(statuses, x)).ToList();`

Comment: @Douglas I thought of this earlier. but this is going to give new `List` which may be problematic if reference of `List` is being used somewhere else. So I go with this idea modifying the `List` itself.